# Boxes Structure messed up

Tags: html, css, structure

I have 3 boxes and the first one it's a bit up then the other 2.. 
The other 2 boxes are ok next to eachother and in the same line.. but first box its not on the same line with the other 2.. its a few pixels up.

**This is the css code**

```css
#services1 {
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    height: 400px;

}

#services2 {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    padding: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;  
    background-color: black;
    height: 400px;
}

#services3 {
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    height: 400px;

}
```

How i can fix that?

Comment: first u have with 33% then u have padding if you make your padding to 0 will them jump on the same line ?

Comment: Where is your HTML markup? And what do you mean by *few pixels up*? Is the `div` itself out of place, or it is the text inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the padding on the first box to 80px(Same as other two boxes). The padding value adds to the overall height of the box.

```css
#services1 {
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 400px;

}

#services2 {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
    padding: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;  
    background-color: tomato;
    height: 400px;
}

#services3 {
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 400px;

}
```

```html
<div id="services1"></div>
<div id="services2"></div>
<div id="services3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this css -

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

on each box. This help you produce *desired and accurate* result.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5ogv1r1/)

Answer (score 0):

Update the first block, you need padding `100px` to `80px`

```
#services1 {
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    height: 400px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of `padding-top: 100px;` other two boxes were having `80px` padding.. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/578m2x4y/1/)**

As all the boxes were of `400px height` with `padding`, you can adjust `height`  or change the `padding to 80px` of 1st box.

```
#services1 {
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 100px 0px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    height: 380px; / *changed value*/

}
```